# Insert new cell into column B and "shift down" values every-time cell A1 changes in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm using Google sheets. I need to automatically add a cell above the existing B1 and shift the values down every-time the value in cell A1 changes.  Column "A" is being populated by a google form. Column B is being manually typed in.

This example is **not** the final product (it is over simplified), but the ability to "automatically insert a cell above an existing cell AND shift existing cells down WHEN the value in another cell changes/updates" is.

Any suggestions or help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

**Example Step One**

```
        Col-A          Col-B
row1    Todd             A+
row2    Bill             C-
row3    Jim              B+
```

**Example Step Two**

```
        Col-A          Col-B
row1    Mike             
row2    Todd             A+
row4    Bill             C-
row3    Jim              B+
```

Comment: Why was this question voted down?

Comment: Maybe because asking for "any suggestions..." sounds like the question is inviting opinion based answers and that kind of questions are of topic on this site. Also the down vote could be because the question doesn't include nothing about similar question on this site or about the research done. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There is an on event that could triggers Google Apps Script functions when a cell value changes, the edit event. It could be used on a simple or on a installable trigger.

In order to be able to insert new lines, you should use a installable on edit trigger.